# in eclipse luna after maven build modified code gets revereted

Tags: java

This is with regards to a eclipse-maven-Spring framework project.

I am doing a revamping for the project. I was working on one of the jsp file where I have to modify the code so I modified the code, saved and did a maven build after the build success I go back to the jsp file to check the changes I don't see the modified code what is see is the old code I tried the following things

1. Made sure I am using right base directory before building
2. Did ALT + F5 -> checked the force update Snapshots/Release

The steps above, have not been successful

Can someone help me and point me in the right direction

Regards,

Chiru